# Does the value of AtomicReference will be set lazily if we assign a function to it which returns some array?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic, atomicreference

I have this piece of code:

```
AtomicReference<List<String>> atomicStrings = new AtomicReference<>();
atomicStrings.set(someFunc());
Thread.sleep(10000);
System.out.print(String.join(",", atomicStrings.get()); // will this print a,b,c ?
```

Where

```
private List<String> someFunc() {
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    new Thread(() -> {
      try {
        list.add("a");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        list.add("b");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        list.add("c");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }).start();

    return list;
}
```

Of course this is a very poor example but i tried to mimic my real test case here by adding delays. My question here is that since someFunc() returns the array right away and the array elements are populated in a different thread, but the result we get is stored in an AtomicReference and we don't get the value until later, the delay i am adding in the main function is more than the delay the new thread spawned will take. Will my returned array be populated will all the elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't "assigning a function" to it, you're *immediately evaluating* `someFunc` and placing the value (a reference to the list) in the `AtomicReference`.

The atomic classes have special *happens-before* constraints, so anything that happens to the list in `someFunc` is guaranteed to be visible to anyone who retrieves the list from the reference, but your modifications to the list in your spawned thread have no *happens-before* relationship to the rest of your program. The behavior is undefined, up to and including `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: I read more about happens-before and find out I don't need AtomicReference in my code. Also in my real code, i am using ExecutorService to assign tasks. I reorg'd my code and gotten rid of AtomicReference all-together. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: Can I close the question if i don't need the answer anymore? Or mark it resolved/answered?

Comment: @Rafay You accepted an answer, which is the Stack Overflow version of marking it resolved. You don't need to do anything more.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the value of AtomicReference will be set lazily if we assign a function to it which returns some array?

First off, `AtomicReference.set()` is immediate and in no ways lazy.  If we look at your code, we see that `someFunc()` returns an `ArrayList` so this will be set immediately into `atomicStrings`.  Unfortunately, the strings are added to the list by another thread and there is no synchronization between the main thread, that is running `someFunc()` and creating the list, and the thread that is adding the strings to the list.  Anytime two different threads are accessing the same object, and especially mutating that object, you need to worry about mutex (race conditions) and memory synchronization.

One thing you could use to fix your specific issue is to use a `BlockingQueue` which is a synchronized class instead of an `ArrayList`.  `BlockingQueue` take care of all of the memory synchronization and mutex locking to ensure that accesses from multiple threads are done appropriately.

```
BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>();
```

Then, when the inner thread calls `queue.add("a");` and then after the 10 seconds expire the main thread calls `queue.iterator()`, they will see the same collection of strings.  There is no need for the `AtomicReference` because the atomic class the main and the inner threads will be sharing is the `ArrayBlockingQueue` .